# Is this a type declaration?

Tags: haskell

Haskell newbie here. I was following this generative art tutorial over the net and came across the following code snippet. I ran it and it works just fine. The thing is I don't understand any bit of it.

```
type Generate a = RandT StdGen (ReaderT World Render) a
```

Is it a product type declaration ? if it is then is it possible to combine a group of types in parentheses like the above ? The way I see, it looks more like a function defined in a type or something like that.

Comment: Well this is a type *alias*. You thus can write `Generate a`, but behind the curtains it is `RandT StdGen (ReaderT World Render) a`.

Comment: It is not a product type declaration. That would be something like `data T = C Int Bool String`. This declares `Generate a` to be exactly the same of the type after the `=`. So, in the library there's this type `RandT`, parametrized over 3 type arguments, and here it is instantiated in some way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it isn’t obvious how to parse this so let’s break it up

```
type
Generate a
=
RandT
  StdGen
  (ReaderT
    World
    Render)
  a
```

So let’s break it down. Line 1 is `type` this means “I’m here defining a type alias”. A type alias is a shorthand for another type and is exactly the same as the type it expands into. Note that `data` means “I’m defining a new datatype and this is how to construct its values”.

Line 2 says “this type will be called `Generate` and is a has parameter `a`” that is the thing `Generate` is a function from some type-level thing (in this case types e.g. `Int` or `Maybe Int` and not e.g. `Maybe`)

Line 4 says that this type is equal to some application of the type constructor `RandT`. This thing has kind `* -> (* -> *) -> * -> *` and it’s meaning is roughly:

1. The first argument is the type of the random number generator
2. The second argument is some Monad
3. A Monad is returned (I.e. the third argument is the type inside the Monad and the result is the Monad)

Let’s look at the second argument. This is an application of `ReaderT`, a type-level thing of kind `* -> (* -> *) -> * -> *`. The first argument is the thing you want to be able to read (the state of the world). The second is some Monad you want to be based on. In this case `Render` which I assume let’s you build up the art as as you go. There is no third so just like currying in normal Haskell, the result of this has kind `* -> *`, which is the kind that was wanted by `RandT`.

The way to read this is: `Generate` is a Monad that lets one use random number generation (with the standard generator), read a value of type `World`, and render art.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one has mentioned it so far, the term you’re looking for is *monad transformer*. Monad transformers let you add various effects on top of an existing type of actions. Examples include `ReaderT`, `StateT`, and `MaybeT`. So in your example you have:

- `Render` is a `Monad` that describes rendering actions.
- `ReaderT World` is a monad *transformer*; when applied to a monad, it produces a monad that can read an immutable environment of type `World`. So `ReaderT World Render` is a monad that describes `Render` actions, and also stores a `World` that can be read with `ask` or `asks` inside actions of this type, e.g., `world <- ask`.
- `RandT StdGen` is a monad transformer which equips a monad with a random number generator of type `StdGen` (a standard generator), which you can access using the methods of `MonadRandom`: `getRandom`, `getRandoms`, `getRandomR`, and `getRandomRs`. So `RandT StdGen (ReaderT World Render)` is a monad that can render things, read the state of the `World`, and generate random numbers from a `StdGen`, e.g., `dieRoll <- getRandomR (1, 6)`.

The `type` declaration just defines `Generate` as an *alias* for `RandT StdGen (ReaderT World Render)`, with one type parameter `a` that indicates the result type of `Generate` actions. Anywhere you see `Generate Foo`, the compiler directly substitutes `RandT StdGen (ReaderT World Render) Foo`.

Comment: thank you for the monad transformer term. now I know what to search for ..